# Difference between java.net.NoRouteToHostException and java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: javax.ws.rs.processingexception

What are the differences between these two exceptions and in which cases can they occur together?

1. javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
2. javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: What do you mean by "together"? Only one exception is ever thrown, never two at the same time - so there is no case where they occur together.

Comment: Together as in, the case in which I encountered these exceptions, first SocketTimeOut exception came and on retrying the call, Host Unreachable exception came.